# Removing user names from welcome screen

Tags: xubuntu, display-manager

I used to have an LXDM in which there was an option not to 'select' a user to login to, but you had to type the desired username, and only then you can type in the password.

I like it better than the "modern" login screen - is there any way to do that on LightDM or do I have to replace it with LXDM?
(I have Xubuntu 15.10 in case it's relevant)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file by the name of the user in `/var/lib/AccountsService/users` that contains these two lines:

```
[User]
SystemAccount=true
```

Restart lightdm either by rebooting or running this from a console:

```
$ sudo service lightdm restart
```

The user will be treated as a SystemAccount and not be displayed.

If the username is `myusername` the file would be:

```
/var/lib/AccountsService/users/myusername
```

The user `myusername` would not show on the Ubuntu login screen, nor would it show in the dropdown of the gear in the tp right of the screen control.

This works in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

You may want to also enable the greeter-show-manual-login function so that the user can login the system.  You can do this by adding this to the `[SeatDefaults]` section of the `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-greeter-wrapper.conf` file.

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-show-manual-login=true
```

Comment: This worked as you said. however, now the LightDM defaults to login to "Guest session".
Can it default to have you type a username?

Comment: @OdedSayar I updated my answer.  I was actually updating it before the comment.  If the answer is accepted you might consider clicking the check mark so that others can easier find a working solution.

Comment: I tried to edit files in .../lightdm/ but it didn't help.
the output of `ls -R` is: 
.:
lightdm.conf.d

./lightdm.conf.d:
50-greeter-wrapper.conf  50-guest-wrapper.conf  50-xserver-command.conf  60-lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf  60-xubuntu.conf  90-nvidia.conf

Comment: @OdedSayar You only have to edit one file: `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-greeter-wrapper.conf`.  I misspelled the path in my answer.  I have corrected it.

Comment: I knew I had to edit only one, I just didn't know which one so I tried one at a time and asked you to be on the safe side